# NSTextView scrolling behavior and selecting behavior

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstextview

I have an NSTextView that I'm outputting text from NSTask. Everything works as expected except the scrolling and selecting behaviors.

1: If I try to scroll up, the position of my scroll snaps back to the bottom instantly after I let go. Any ideas? I've looked through quite a bit of documentation about this and can't find anything about it.

2: If I select text, it removes it. I just want it to select so I can copy and paste. Lost on this one too.

Any tips or pointers would be most welcome. Thanks.

```
- (id)init
{
    [super init];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(readPipe:)
                                                 name:NSFileHandleReadCompletionNotification 
                                               object:nil];

    return self;
}

- (void)kicked
{
    task = [[NSTask alloc] init];

    [task setLaunchPath:[self.kickLocationTextField stringValue]];
    [task setArguments:kickBuild];

    NSPipe *pipe = [[NSPipe alloc] init];
    fileHandle = [pipe fileHandleForReading];
    [fileHandle readInBackgroundAndNotify];

    [task setStandardOutput:pipe];
    [task setStandardError:pipe];

    [task launch];

    [task release];
    [pipe release];
}


- (void)readPipe:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    NSData *data;
    NSString *text;

    if( [notification object] != fileHandle )
    {
        return;
    }

    data = [[notification userInfo] objectForKey:NSFileHandleNotificationDataItem];
    text = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

    [nsTaskOutput insertText:text];

    [text release];
    if (data != 0)
    {
        [fileHandle readInBackgroundAndNotify];
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you replacing the entire text in the text view whenever you get output from the task? Please edit the question and post the code you use to grab output from the task and add it to the text view.

Comment: Updated. According to the docs for NSTextView... if nothing is selected in the view it will append the next incoming string. If there IS selected text... it will replace it.

Everything works as expected, with the exception of those previous two questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this instead of `insertText:`:

```
NSScroller *scroller = nTaskOutput.enclosingScrollView.verticalScroller;
BOOL shouldScrollToBottom = scroller.doubleValue == 1.0;
NSTextStorage *ts = nTaskOutput.textStorage;
[ts replaceCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(ts.length, 0) withString:text];
if (shouldScrollToBottom) {
    NSRect bounds = nTaskOutput.bounds;
    [nTaskOutput scrollPoint:NSMakePoint(NSMaxX(bounds), NSMaxY(bounds))];
}
```

Comment: NICE! That works great!!

The only downside is that it caused it to not automatically scroll to the bottom with new output.

Comment: I've modified my answer but it's just a guess.

Comment: Bingo! I'll have to breakdown what you did here. I've never used NSTextStorage or NSScroller, so it looks like it's time to dig into those sections of the docs.

Thank you very much Rob.

Comment: Looks like your scroll-to-bottom implementation is the equivalent of "if(scroll is at bottom) then scroll to bottom" correct?

Comment: It's more like “if it was scrolled to bottom before inserting, then scroll to bottom after inserting.”